# Spring cloud stream schema registry deployed on standalone tomcat

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have Schema Registry server and Schema Registry client on spring boot 1.5.2.

I am sending avro messages to kafka binder. Using Brooklyn.SR3. Schemas are persisted to postgres DB. Everything works fine while I am starting spring boot main class.

When try to deploy on standalone tomcat there is a error when try to send message to binder:

```
caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.client.DefaultSchemaRegistryClient.register(DefaultSchemaRegistryClient.java:53)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AvroSchemaRegistryClientMess****ageConverter.resolveSchemaForWriting(AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.java:187)****
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AbstractAvroMessageConverter.convertToInternal(AbstractAvroMessageConverter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$ContentTypeConvertingInterceptor.preSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:237)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:538)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:415)
```

I switched to Tomcat 9 and now getting some other error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface java.util.Map] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:917)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:655)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:407)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.client.DefaultSchemaRegistryClient.register(DefaultSchemaRegistryClient.java:54)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.resolveSchemaForWriting(AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.java:219)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AbstractAvroMessageConverter.convertToInternal(AbstractAvroMessageConverter.java:174)
at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:193)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$ContentTypeConvertingInterceptor.preSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:238)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:538)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:415)
```

UPDATE:

The problem that cause 404 was root of deployed application on standalone tomcat. I fixed that but now another error raise:

```
Failed to register schema: <302 Found,{Location=[/csl/], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Date=[Mon, 27 Mar 2017 10:08:40 GMT]}>
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.client.DefaultSchemaRegistryClient.register(DefaultSchemaRegistryClient.java:64)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.resolveSchemaForWriting(AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.java:219)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AbstractAvroMessageConverter.convertToInternal(AbstractAvroMessageConverter.java:174)
at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:193)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$ContentTypeConvertingInterceptor.preSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:238)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:538)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:415)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the server as a standalone process? What's the value of `spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint` on your Application? I would also recommend bumping to Chelsea RC1, we have made a lot of improvements on the schema registration and caching.

Comment: Switched to Chelsea RC1. Tomcat is running as a standalone process. Schema registry is on same server: spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint=http://localhost:8080 Still getting same error. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you could be missing. But I just setup a project following the same base information you gave and everything is working. Here's the configuration properties:

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you could be missing. But I just setup a project following the same base information you gave and everything is working. Here's the configuration properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=application/*+avro
server.port=8080
spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint=http://localhost:8080
spring.cloud.stream.schema.avro.dynamic-schema-generation-enabled=true
```

And I have one class that has configuration and a rest endpoint to send messages

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSchemaRegistryServer
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@RestController
public class SchemaApplication {

    @Autowired
    private Source source;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchemaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/messages", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void sendMessage(){
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Joe");
        user.setFavoriteColor("Blue");
        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(user).build());
    }


}
```

Messages are being published to rabbit using the correct header : `application/vnd.user.v1+avro`

One thing that I noted is that your endpoint lacks the protocol `http`, the error thrown is usually an malformed protocol exception during startup.

Also, I'd suggest leaving the server as a separate entity from your app, you want to avoid any classpath clashing between your app with business entities and the server.

Also when querying http://localhost/user/avro I get back the generated schema: `{"id":1,"version":1,"subject":"user","format":"avro","definition":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"User\",\"namespace\":\"io.acme\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"favoriteColor\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"}`

Comment: deployed Schema Registry war on separate tomcat. I have protocol http in front of url.  But still getting 302 Found...on post schema and when try to send message to kafka.

Comment: The type of broker does not really matter. Have you tried to reach the schema server directly using a POST and then getting the schema back.The docs have a section on the endpoints of the server. See if you can reach it directly

Comment: I deployed Registry server on another tomcat and I can get schemas with (http)://localhost:8090/sr/schemas/1. Trying to send message to binder from another app that has spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint=(http)://localhost:8090/sr and still getting 302 found. Spring is doing this redirect but can't see why.

Comment: exact error is: `org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'MY_CHANNEL_NAME'; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to register schema: <302 Found,{Location=[/sr/], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Date=[Tue, 28 Mar 2017 11:40:30 GMT]}>, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={`

Comment: The only thing I can think about is if you have something in your network, like proxies for example. I have deployed this on embedded and separate tomcat and I can't reproduce your error. How did you get the schemas, did you use curl or a browser (which can follow 302 links). If you curl with verbose output, what do you see. Networking is the only thing that comes to my mind at the moment

Comment: It was stupid / at the end of spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint=http://localhost:8080/csl/

Answer (score 0):

It was stupid / at the end of 
spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint=http://localhost:8080/csl**/**